# counting frequency of data using dictionary

Tags: java

I have a data with a class attribute and I don't know the all the value of the class.
I want to count the classes frequencies
e.g
data

```
 | data | class|  
 |  1   |  X   |
 |  2   |  Y   |
 |  3   |  Y   |
```

the result :

```
 class X occurs 1 times
 class Y occurs 2 times
```

If I found new type of class I need to save it in dictionary but if I found a class that already in dictionary I should increase the count.
so how can I handle it using java?

Comment: Your problem is not really clear, do you have some code to show us ? Some sample data ?

Comment: Sounds like hashmap of integers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `HashMap` to store the number of time you have found every class:

```
final String data = "data 1 class X\ndata 2 class Y\ndata 3 class X";
final Scanner sc = new Scanner(data);
final HashMap<String, Integer> classes = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
    final String line = sc.nextLine();
    final String clazz = line.substring(line.indexOf("class")+6);

    if (!classes.containsKey(clazz))
        classes.put(clazz, 0);
    classes.put(clazz, classes.get(clazz)+1);
}

for (Entry<String, Integer> entry : classes.entrySet())
    System.out.println("Class "+entry.getKey()+" found "+entry.getValue()+" time(s).");
```

Output:

```
Class Y found 1 time(s).
Class X found 2 time(s).
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are classifying something. Here is a version(similar to Florent Bayle's, but a complete working example, just provide your filename):

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

public class Classify {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        BufferedReader reader=new BufferedReader(new FileReader("YOUR_FILENAME"));
        String line;
        Map<String,AtomicInteger> classByCount=new HashMap<>();
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            final String[] lineArray = line.split("\\s");
            String clazz=lineArray[lineArray.length-1];
            AtomicInteger count=classByCount.get(clazz);
            if(count==null)classByCount.put(clazz,(count=new AtomicInteger(0)));
            count.incrementAndGet();
        }
        for(Map.Entry<String,AtomicInteger> entry:classByCount.entrySet())
            System.out.printf("class '%s':%d\n",entry.getKey(),entry.getValue().get());
    }
}
```